# Recommendations for good books on mechanical vibrations

Tags: resource-recommendations, oscillators, vibrations, coupled-oscillators

I'm looking for books that explain/model vibration concepts such as multi degree of freedom vibrations from a mechanical vibrations standpoint (not waves). I'd prefer if it has proofs for most concepts and goes into the matter from a fundamental level. Multiple books covering different topics are fine.

Comment: any upper-division (3rd year) mechanical engineering textbook covering dynamical systems will contain what you seek.

Comment: @nielsnielsen The problem I'm facing is, the books that I'm using don't go into detail on things like why any vibration can be expressed as sum of modes, what is the physical meaning of orthogonality etc. They only provide equations and leave it to us to figure it out. I'd appreciate it if you can suggest any book that can provide insights on topics like that from a fundamental level. Thanks

Comment: I studied this in grad school 40 years ago and am sorry that I cannot recommend any currently-available texts.